# Equivalent to JGraph for JavaFX8?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, jgrapht, jgraph

I want to port an old swing tool which uses an also old version of JGraph to JavaFX8. However, since JGraph is a Swing-Based library, is thought about replacing it, too. So, is there something equivalent to JGraph, but working with JavaFX8?

Comment: No, there isn't, at least no open source that's production ready. I think yFiles is built on JavaFX, but that's commercial and expensive. But depending on your needs you could say that JavaFX is a graph tool itself. What are your requirements?

Comment: Well, the old tool that I have allows to draw specific graphs in a gui and to run algorithms on them. Via a plugin system you can specify other types of graphs and new types of algorithms, e.g. finite automota and their handling of input. I don't know yet, which parts of jgraph are used for this, as I did not dig deep enough into it yet, but I suspect, that a lot of the functionality of JGraph is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is there something equivalent to JGraph, but working with JavaFX8?

Following [Jonathan Giles Blog](http://jonathangiles.net/blog/), I can't remember having read anything about a JavaFX based graph library yet -> so, most likely, no

But you should be able to use Swing controls in JavaFX: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html

Comment: I assume, then the best solution would be looking into jGraph and keeping the non-ui parts, while replacing the swing parts with javafx. However, I'm not quite sure how much work that would be...

Comment: @bln-tom If you do any such work, it would be great to here about it!

Comment: not doing it at the moment. However, as soon, as I find some more time for the project, I will notify you